# Citing books that do not give a denominational perspective

Tags: discussion

Although I know it is important or recommended to give out the denominational perspective, I find that some sources just don't give out the denomination.

From the top of my head currently, I can think of three:

- The Bible For Dummies
- The Complete Idiot's Guide To The Bible
- The Illustrated Bible: Story by Story

What should we do about sources that are written by interdenominational groups or groups that downplay denominational differences?

Answer (score 2):

If a question asks what a denomination believes about X, and a source says, "Christians believe Y," then it's not a good source for answering the question. If it says, "[Denomination] believes Y," then it's fine.

If a question asks about an interpretation of something in the Bible that doesn't need denominational scoping, and a source says, "Here's what it means," then it's fine.

Comment: I'm most interested in the scenario that your second paragraph describes, because I've taken a lot of info from the above books, and honestly, I have no idea where they're coming from. :P

Comment: Could you give a specific scenario?

Comment: *The Illustrated Bible: Story by Story* talks about the Mary, mother of Jesus, as the Second Eve.

Comment: Can you give an example of a question on this site where you wouldn't know whether to say that in an answer?

Comment: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/25879/in-which-denominations-do-people-consider-mary-mother-of-jesus-to-be-the-seco

Comment: @DoubleU While there are decent popular level books, I doubt any of the ones you mentioned in the question are. Do Christian bookstores sell them? I wouldn't say they were written by interdenominal groups, instead they're written by secular publishers who want to fill a gap in their Idiots Guide to Everything range! If you're interested in some better overview books Christians actually use, then we can probably help suggest some. That would be a good Meta question.

Answer (score -3):

Absolutely nothing.

Someone may cite a source to fortify an answer to a denomination-specific question. There's nothing to be concerned about. Not even a little bit. Crisis averted. Please enjoy your weekend.